# Overriding CSS for ::selection back to browser defaults

Tags: css

I've got a site in which I'm dealing with a CSS specification that I want to override. One of the things it specifies is a `background` and `color` for the `::selection` property.

I can override these with other explicitly defined `background`s and `color`s, but that's not really what I want. What I want is just to be able to revert to the browser defaults: to let Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc., just do whatever they'd normally do (e.g., Safari uses a light blue background, but I'd rather not hard-code that).

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to how CSS works in the cascade, there is no way to revert styles on a particular element.  Styles from the User Agent declarations [have lower precedence than all other declarations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order), and the ability to revert rules does not exist.  The only solution is to get rid of those styles in the first place (although I can understand how that may be difficult), hard code the necessary styles, or choose yet another style that at least looks okay.

Comment: Yep; easier when the default is inherit or transparent in every browser. Outline or form elements have more challenging defaults...